# How do I welcome different names in a function?

Tags: javascript

Below is my (not working) code. I'm trying to write a function that allows me to enter in any name into the console.log and then have that name attached to the message. Please see below for clarification:

```
  function checkAge(name, age) {
  name = {};
  if (age >= 21) {
    return ("Welcome," + {} + "!");
  }
  else return ("Go home," + {} + "!");
}
console.log(checkAge('Adrian', 22)); //Welcome,[object Object]!
```

Expected result should be 'Welcome, Adrian!' (and not Welcome, [object, Object]!). BUT I don't want to hard code names so I can't just write
name === 'Adrian' since it needs to work for any name. Any advice? Thank you! :)

Comment: `name = {};` - this clobbers the input argument `name` with an empty Object - which is why you get `[object Object]` in the console

Comment: You pass a name as a parameter and then immediately overwrite it.

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you think `{}` means.

Comment: I didn't realize all I had to do was write the name in! I'm new so I'm learning. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `name = {};` you are reassigning parameter name and not passing the parameter to the return of string.

```
function checkAge(name, age) {
  if (age >= 21) {
    return ("Welcome," + name + "!");
  }
  else return ("Go home," + name + "!");
}

console.log(checkAge('Adrian', 22));

output >> Welcome,Adrian!
```

Comment: Thank you! @luminous_Dev! I didn't realize all I had to do was write the name in! Thanks everyone!